# grep doesn't search double quotes well. not even with \"

Tags: bash, grep

- On Ubuntu 16.04 *

i have a file with the following line:

`s:15:\"https://cnn.com\"`

`cat myfile.txt | grep https://cnn.com` works.

But I'd like to find the `s:15` portion too as well so I try:

`cat myfile.txt | grep 's:15:\"https://cnn.com\"'`

Zero results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Grep doesn't care about quotes at all. You need to learn how your *shell* deals with them. Try `echo 's:15:\"https://cnn.com\"'`. Is this what you want to grep?

Comment: Then how would you find a string like s:15: followed by a double quote, followed by cnn.com and followed by another double quote?

Comment: Yes. doesn't work. zero results, while `cat myfile.txt | grep https://cnn.com` GIVES the result back.

Comment: @JasonGenX, `echo 's:15"cnn.com"' > temp; grep emp -e 's:15"cnn.com"'` works on my machine

Comment: So you have that literal string in the file, right? `grep` doesn't care about quotes, but it does care about *backslashes*. Try `fgrep` instead.

Comment: `echo 's:15"cnn.com"' > temp; grep emp -e 's:15"cnn.com"'` gives `grep: emp: No such file or directory` - I'm on Ubnutu 16.04

Comment: @JasonGenX, that `emp` was clearly a typo for `temp`, which is to say, intended to be a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your command is not the quotes but the backslashes. As you have the backslashes in your original file, you need to match the backslashes with grep too (so, escape them):

```
$ cat myfile.txt | grep 's:15:\\"https://cnn.com\\"'
s:15:\"https://cnn.com\"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using '\"' is that you are doubling down on having the shell process your quote. You either need to backslash just the quote character `\"` or use the single quotes without backslash `'"'`. Doing both will have grep searching for a backslash and a quote.

Try

> grep s:15:\"https://cnn.com\"

or

> grep 's:15:"https://cnn.com"'

Edit: My above answer is incorrect due to there being backslash characters in the data. Since grep uses a backslash as an escape character, you need to provide it with a double backslash to match a single occurrence.

Comment: Sorry. Zero results with both.

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice that your file actually had backslash characters. You were correctly handling the quotes, but grep needs a double backslash to match a single one.